# Showing a subset of a topological manifold is a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Theorem:
>
> Let M be a topological manifold and let U be any open subset of M, with the subspace topology. Then U is a topological manifold.

Now, the only problem I face is showing that U is locally euclidean.

> Recall: Locally euclidean
>
> A topological space U is locally euclidean if, $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \forall \bar{u} \in U$, there exists an open set $\alpha \subseteq U$ containing $\bar{u}$ homeomorphic to some open set $\beta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since $U$ is open in $M$, you should be able to transfer the locally-euclidean property from $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $U$ is an open subset of $M$. Let $u\in U\subseteq M$ Then there exists an open set $\alpha\subseteq M$ containing $u$ and homeomorphic to an open subset $\beta\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ via the homeomorphism $f:\alpha\to\beta$.

Then $\alpha\cap U$ is open in $U$ (and also $\alpha$), contains $u$ and is homeomorphic to $f(\alpha\cap U)$ which is open in $\mathbb R^n$ being the image of the open set $\alpha\cap U$ under the open map $f$

Thus $U$ is locally Euclidean of same dimension $n$ as $M$.

Comment: I dont understand "Then there exists an open set $\alpha\subseteq M$ containing $u$ and homeomorphic to an open subset $\beta\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ via the homeomorphism $f:\alpha\to\beta$. "

Comment: Since $M$ is locally Euclidean, by the definition you mentioned, there is such an open set $\alpha$

Comment: That is true but how do you justify the homeomorphism to $\beta$?

Comment: Of course it exists. Since $M$ is known to be locally Euclidean you must have for every $u\in M$ open sets $u\in\alpha\subseteq M$ and $\beta\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ and a homeomorphism $f_\alpha:\alpha\to\beta$. I am just calling this $f_\alpha$ as $f$ here

Comment: it is hereditary

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a topological manifold then you have a maximal atlas $\{(U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}\}$. If $U \subset M$ is open then $\{(U_{\alpha} \cap U, \phi_{\alpha}|_U)\}$ is the corresponding maximal atlas for $U$.